# How to replicate Gmail ipad web-app split pane in HTML5 CSS3 and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, gmail

Today I was wondering how GMAIL web app for **iPad** works.

Basically, there the page is **split** in two pane, both are **scrollable** and the page is **anchored** to the browser.

Is it possible to replicate this for a desktop web app? I tried to figure that out. The only way I can think of is about *iframes*, however it is not the best way.

Any suggestions?